# status bar is overlapping with navigation bar when showing uiviewcontroller with uipresentviewcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am presenting a uiviewcontroller in my app but the controller is overlapping with status bar. It only has navigation bar and because of this my barbutton is overlapping with battery icon in status bar. Any idea in showing navigation bar below status bar? I searched a lot but could not find a solution. My code to present viewcontroller:

```
let timeVCObejct = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TimeConfigurationViewController") as? TimeConfigurationViewController
    timeVCObejct?.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(timeVCObejct!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Can you please attach screen short.

Comment: You will have to move the navigation bar 20px lower.

Answer (score 0):

Use this property for your VC, in-order to avoid overlap of ur statusbar with your VC
Swift :

> self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []

ObjectiveC C

> self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;